# Chrome rendering color weird

Tags: macos, google-chrome, colors, rendering, artifacts

My Dell 2709w monitor recently started acting weird.
On some page it renders different colors, where it shouldn't.

It only does this on the external monitor, not the macbook itself.
And it is only in chrome. safari and firefox does not do this.

I am running macOS Sierra

Here is what it does:
[image]

Those light spots should not be there!

Comment: Besides Canary, did anyone make any progress here?  Most websites still look terrible on my macbook.  Crazy that this is a known bug and nothing is done about it (also on Sierra, using a Macbook Air)

Comment: Nothing here yet. Bummer that it also happens on your macbook screen. It is only my external screen that´s affected by this.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the contents of the [bug report here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=633805#c16), a workaround that has worked for me is to set the "GPU rasterization" flag to *Enabled* in the Chrome configuration flags editor:

[chrome://flags/#enable-gpu-rasterization](http://chrome://flags/#enable-gpu-rasterization)

Thanks to Adam Lunn below for the link to the bug report.

Comment: I got the same bug on Chrome since I'm running under Sierra. Your solution works for me! Thanks ;)

Comment: This didn't work for me :(

Comment: Didn't work for me either:/

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting this issue too when connected to an external monitor. Are you using Sierra by any chance? It might be an issue with that.

Here's an example from me - this should be solid red background on an HTML page in Chrome 53:

[This should be solid red, but it has artifacts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MS2w.png)

Comment: Yes thats exactly what i am experiencing. and yes i am on Sierra, ive updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: Seems to be an existing issue with Sierra? https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=633805

Comment: I downloaded Canary from [here](http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel) and the issue is gone completely :)

Comment: Just tried Canary, but the issue remains :(

Comment: I also tried Canary (as of Oct 13th 2016) and the rendering problems are gone. Let's hope they integrate the fix into Chrome stable soon, this is annoying!

Answer (score 0):

I' getting same issue with Chrome 53 but also with Chrome Canary 56 and Atom.

Seems to happen on empty solid colors.